# ¿Cómo excluir retweets y respuestas en la API de twitter con Codebird?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de obtener solo el último tweet de una cuenta especifica usando la API de twitter, en el resultado también estoy recibiendo respuestas y retweets.

Así que quiero excluir respuestas y retweets.

Como hacerlo que alguien me ayude.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>twitter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codebird.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

</head>
<body>
    

<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="content-text"></div>

    
        

    <script>
    var cb = new Codebird;
    cb.setConsumerKey('AtROcvPkhlQhBPbpAIywBxb','VEJkgugMKsfysLjDqOOtiX0sXO69zjdLvZaGVJJtejacDCyo');
    cb.setToken('45064296714162176-ATsuycQD3wFFVzenW4x5UYGO0jjNSC','VviLcWUEvpXG2lPIZlFv9fEtEgzpPXOv0Evb9ck9Hbf');

        var params = { 
        q: 'sttmed',
        count: 1,
        
        
}; cb . __call ( "search_tweets" , params, function (reply) {
   // ... 
   document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(reply);



});

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Espero que esas *keys* no sean información delicada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codebird lo único que hace es pasar la consulta que realizas a la API de Twitter.

Para poder filtrar las respuestas y retweets de los resultados tienes que utilizar el parámetro *filter*.

La query que pasas quedaría de la siguiente forma en tu caso:

```
var params = { 
    q: 'from:sttmed AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies',
    result_type: 'recent',
    count: 1
}
```

Para más información acerca de otros operadores que puedes utilizar al trabajar con la API te refiero a la documentación oficial: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators

Comment: Amigo, ya lo solucione de una manera, saber como puedo pintarlos en pantalla? lo tengo así y no me funciona:    document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(reply); y si le pongo .statuses.text tampoco me funciona

Comment: *statuses* es un arreglo. Tienes que acceder al primer, y en este caso único, elemento de la siguiente forma: reply.statuses[0].text

Comment: Perdón, sabes como lo puedo poner en el content-text?

Comment: Usando el método *getElementById* de *document*, completo quedaría así: 
document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = reply.statuses[0].text;

Comment: Por fin encontré a alguien con la respuesta correcta, perfecto!